# Calculating Accuracy Assessment in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, remote-sensing, image, accuracy

Is there a way to calculate an `accuracy assessment` in QGIS?

I have around 300 points. At each point I extracted the value of the pixel. I compared the extracted value with the value which should be there. Now I have a table with two columns: One is the extracted value from the raster, one is the value which I typed in manually (the correct value).

How would I calculate the `users accuracy` and `Kappa` with that? Is there a tool to do that?

Comment: What exactly should be calculated? A simply math expression between those values per row?

Comment: @bugmenot123 whatever needs to be done to get an accuracy assesment (useres accuracy, over all accuracy, kappa, ...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/). It has Accuracy assessment calculation, as you can see below, but I didn't try it yet.

There is also a [help](http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/semi-automatic-classification-plugin.html) about the plugin, and [Youtube video about accuracy assessment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxBwMQnyZKw).

[image]

Comment: Would that tool accept shapefiles, that have already all the information in them? So, I would not create the shapefile with that tool, but rather feed it a shapefile where two columns indicate the extracted value at the pixel, and the other column with the value I typed in manually.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it may accept the shapefile that you already have. It is better to read the turorial, because I didn't work on this tool extensively. I mostly use commercial software for such analysis.

Comment: I worked with this tool (SCP) and its a black box. Sometimes stuff works, sometime it does not... Thats why I am looking for another method.